# I am using Gmail with a vanity account alias and external SMTP server (AWS SES). My first email is not being threaded

Tags: email, gmail, mail-forwarding

So this is a minor inconvenience but I am curious if anyone well versed in email forwarding and Gmail can help me.

I have a vanity domain I'll call code@coder.dev.  I am using it as an alias for my personal gmail code@gmail.com.

- I compose the initial message, message_id=A, in Gmail, and send it through AWS SES SMTP.
- AWS SES creates its own message_id=B and sends it to end user (stranger@gmail.com)
- stranger@gmail.com replies with message_id=C, and sends it to AWS SES.  It also sets References: B
- My email forwarding Lambda forwards the message to me (code@gmail.com), with message_id=D.
- Gmail does not show A in the same thread as D, on my end (code@gmail.com)

Note that if I reply to D, and stranger replies, and I reply back, etc. etc., all those messages are threaded together.  Because at this point, we are building up the References: list with ids we have both seen before.  It's only A that is left out.

What's funny/sad is message A also contains X-Gmail-Original-Message-ID: A, and that makes it to stranger@gmail.com, but then stranger *doesn't send that header back in message C or use it in the References: list*.  Google doesn't know how to talk to itself :|

Also see https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html

Comment: Did you ever resolve this in any way? It seems strange this is still an issue today.  I am considering a custom SMTP proxy to correctly put the original message id into the References header.